# Automatically fix mount on systemd unit failure due to bad mount

Tags: mount, systemd, rtorrent

For quite some time, I've been fighting a problem with my Raspberry Pi having difficulty to maintain a connection to my external HDD. Sometimes it just randomly throws I/O error, and when that happens, my rtorrent service unit fails with it. Now I tried many things, this is the solution that I have now:

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
KillMode=none
ExecStartPre=/home/pi/mount_media.sh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -d -m -fa -S rtorrent /usr/bin/rtorrent
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -w -s 2 /usr/bin/rtorrent
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Where mount_media.sh simply remounts the directory.

Stuff I also tried but didn't work:

- OnFailure start different unit which remounts the directory
- Start the unit with a script, which remounts the drive and then starts rtorrent

Right now, this approach has left me with "`cannot access 'Media': Transport endpoint is not connected`"

Forgot to add: /media/Media is my mount point

So how should I take care of a moot point randomly disconnecting?

Comment: Have you got a strong enough transformer to keep up with an HDD?

Comment: I think so, I connect it through USB hub, which is power by a 5V, 2A adapter.

Comment: Also no other device is connected to the hub so the 5V, 2A are going directly to the HDD